# Convert Date TImestamp In Presto

Tags: oracle, hive, presto

is there any way to convert from 2022-06-15 10:21:05.698000000 to  this 2022-06-15 10:21:05  format?

I have data in hive (Datatype is string) which contains data like this 2022-06-15 10:21:05.698000000. I need to insert this data in oracle, in oracle data type is date. I am using below query while selecting the data from hive.

```
select hive_date,cast(coalesce(substr(A.hive_date, 1,19),substr(A.hive_date2,1,19)) as timestamp) 
as oracle_date from test A limit 10;
```

It's showing below output.

```
hive_date                                                  oracle_date
2022-06-15 10:21:05.698000000          |                   2022-06-15 10:21:05.000
```

I want to convert this till seconds **2022-06-15 10:21:05** so i can insert into it in oracle. Can someone plz suggest me.

Comment: all seems to be good. oracle_date is a timestamp which is equivalent to date in oracle. any error while exporting?

Comment: yes It's showing literal does not match format string , when I removed this column value all other records are loaded without error

Comment: Are you exporting from a table/partition or view?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [date functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#mysql-date-functions) - `date_parse` and `date_format`:

```sql
select date_format(date_parse('2022-06-15 10:21:05.698000000', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2022-06-15 10:21:05 |

Also I would suggest using `coalesce` before manipulations i.e. in original attempt `coalesce(substr(A.hive_date, 1,19),substr(A.hive_date2,1,19))` -> `substr(coalesce(A.hive_date, A.hive_date2), 1, 19)`

Also possibly you need to just use `trim` on the data, like:

```sql
substr(trim(coalesce(A.hive_date, A.hive_date2)), 1, 19)
```

Or:

```sql
select date_format(
        date_parse(
            trim(coalesce(A.hive_date, A.hive_date2)),
            '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f'
        ),
        '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that all you need is:

```
SELECT cast('2022-06-15 10:21:05.698000000' AS timestamp(0));
```

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2022-06-15 10:21:06 |

---

But, if it needs to be a string, this truncates:

```
SELECT date_format(timestamp '2022-06-15 10:21:05.698000000', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2022-06-15 10:21:05 |

Or this method rounds:

```
SELECT cast(cast('2022-06-15 10:21:05.698000000' AS timestamp(0)) AS varchar);
```

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2022-06-15 10:21:06 |